# Issue with File Upload to S3 using Filament in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-filament

I'm relatively new to Filament, and I'm encountering an issue with uploading files to Amazon S3 using Filament. Strangely, my Laravel code for file uploads works perfectly fine. I have followed the documentation closely, but I seem to be missing something. Here's how I achieve file uploads in Laravel:

```
$profilePicture = $request->file('profile_picture');
$profilePictureName = time() . '.' . $profilePicture->extension();
$file = $profilePicture->storeAs('profile_pictures', $profilePictureName, 's3');
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($file);
$userModel->avatar = $url;
$userModel->save();
return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Profile picture updated successfully',
    'user' => StudentResource::make($userModel),
]);
```

Now, here's my Filament code for file uploads:

```
Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('file')
    ->required()
    ->label('File')
    ->maxSize(10240)
    ->maxFiles(1)
    ->disk('s3')
    ->directory('handbooks')
    ->visibility('public')
    ->placeholder('Upload File'),
```

When I try to upload a file using Filament, I receive a success message, but the file is not being uploaded to S3. Additionally, the file path and name returned are not as expected (e.g., handbook\'filename'). In contrast, my Laravel code provides the public URL for the uploaded file.

I have thoroughly checked the documentation but couldn't identify the issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

PHP version:

```
   PHP 8.2.15
```

Composer:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.296",
        "eightynine/filament-excel-import": "^3.0",
        "filament/filament": "^3.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.22",
        "pxlrbt/filament-excel": "^2.3",
        "twilio/sdk": "^7.13"
    },
```

config/filesystem.php

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 's3'),

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('A3_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('A3_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('A3_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('A3_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],
```

config/filament.php

```
'default_filesystem_disk' => 's3',
```

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems to upload because the filament sends it to a temporary file that is configured in config/livewire.php , mine is 'disk' => 'local'. That's why it looks like it uploads but doesn't. So when you click save the link gets messed up. In my case on site this works. But somehow the server is giving an error. I've already tried changing the livewire temp file to s3 but it gives a CORS error. I do not know what to do

Comment: Cross-check if your AWS credentials are correct or have the right permissions to the bucket.